# MongoDB using agregation to sort after date: prezent, past, future

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an event schema that looks like:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  payment: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Payment",
    required: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  eventImage: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  pin: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  welcomeMessage: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  showImages: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: true,
  },
  showMessages: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
  started: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
  isDemo: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
  demoId: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  mb: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: 0,
  },
  guestsNr: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: 0,
  },
  cardText: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  cardTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

eventSchema.statics.build = (attrs) => {
  return new Event(attrs);
};

const Event = mongoose.model("Event", eventSchema);

module.exports = Event;
```

I must arrange the events by date in an array. The first set in the array should consist of events occurring on the same day as today. Following that, I'd like to place events with future dates, and finally, events with past dates.

```
const today = new Date();
      today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

 const events = await Event.aggregate([
        {
          $match: query,
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "payments",
            localField: "payment",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "payment",
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$payment",
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            sortField: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $eq: [
                    {
                      $dateToString: {
                        format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                        date: "$date",
                      },
                    },
                    { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: today } },
                  ],
                },
                then: -1,
                else: {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $gt: ["$date", today],
                    },
                    then: 0, // Future
                    else: 1, // Past
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      
        {
          $sort: { sortField: 1 },
        },
        {
          $skip: skip,
        },
        {
          $limit: pageSize,
        },
      ]);
```

This section appears to be functioning correctly:

```
else: {
  $cond: {
    if: {
      $gt: ["$date", today],
    },
    then: 0, // Represents future dates
    else: 1, // Represents past dates
  },
},
```

I believe the if condition is not being satisfied, and I'm uncertain about the reason:

```
      if: {
                  $eq: [
                    {
                      $dateToString: {
                        format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                        date: "$date",
                      },
                    },
                    { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: today } },
                  ],
                },
                then: -1,
```